# Ash - Complex Variables - Proof of Maximum Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I am self studying Ash & Novinger's Complex Variables. In [subsection 2.4.12 of the book](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV2.pdf), the authors are trying to prove that if $f$ is analytic on an open connected set $\Omega$ and $\lvert f \rvert$ assumes a local maximum at some point in $\Omega$ then $f$ is constant in $\Omega$.

The outline of the proof is as follows: Suppose that $f$ assumes a local maximum at $z_0 \in \Omega$. If $f(z_0)=0$ then $f(z)=0$ on some neighbourhood $B(z_0, \delta)$ of $z_0$ and identity theorem implies $f\equiv 0$ on $\Omega$. So, the authors assume $f(z_0)\ne 0$. By the Cauchy's Integral formula, we have that
\begin{align*}
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0 + re^{it})\,dt \leadsto 1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\,dt
\end{align*}
for any $r<\delta$. Using this, the authors then show that $\left\lvert f(z)/f(z_0) \right\rvert =1$ on $B(z_0, \delta)$. They claim that $\Re \left( f(z)/f(z_0) \right) =1$ on $B(z_0, \delta)$ but do not prove it. I am stuck here.

Here's my attempt: Let $r < \delta$. Then we have that $1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\,dt$. Taking real part both sides, we get $1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Re \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\,dt \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \Re\left(\frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right) \, dt \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left\lvert \frac{f(z_0 +re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right\rvert dt \le 1$. Note that the last inequality is due to the fact that $\lvert f(z_0 + re^{it})\rvert \le \lvert f(z_0) \rvert$ for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$. If it happened that $\Re\left(\frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right) \ge 1$ for each $t\in [0,2\pi]$ then I could have concluded that $\Re\left(\frac{f(z)}{f(z_0)} \right) =1$ for each $z \in B(z_0, \delta)$. But this may not hold!

Any hints would be appreciated!

---

EDIT: Following this up from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4653633/151611), we have that from my attempt that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\underbrace{\left[ \left\lvert \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right\rvert - \Re \left( \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right) \right]}_{\ge 0} \, dt = 0$. By using continuity, we can then complete the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Re \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\,dt \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \Re\left(\frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right) \, dt \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left\lvert \frac{f(z_0 +re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right\rvert dt \le 1$ implies that $|\frac{f(z_0 +re^{it})}{f(z_0)}|=1$ for all $t$. It also implies that $\Re\left(\frac{f(z_0 + re^{it})}{f(z_0)} \right)=|\frac{f(z_0 +re^{it})}{f(z_0)}|$. These two together imply that $\frac{f(z_0 +re^{it})}{f(z_0)}=1$ for all $t$. This is true for all $r <\delta$ so $\frac {f(z)} {f(z_0)} =1$ for $z \in B(z_0,\delta)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the assumption that $f$ has a local maximum at $z_0$, i.e. there exists a $\delta>0$, so that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|$ for all $z\in B_r(z_0)$ and $0<r<\delta$. Stated differently, one has $\left|\frac{f(z)}{f(z_0)}\right|\leq 1$ for all $z\in B_r(z_0)$.

So assume that there exists a $z_1\in B_r(z_0)$, so that $\left|\frac{f(z_1)}{f(z_0)}\right|< 1$. Writing $z_1 = z_0 + re^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, the continuity of $f$ implies that there exists a non-empty open neighborhood $N\subset[0,2\pi]$ of $\theta$, so that $\left|\frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\right|<1$ for all $t\in N$.

However, this means that the integral will be "too small" and thus yield a contradiction to the formula you wrote:
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{f(z_0)}d t\right|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \int\limits_N \underbrace{\left|\frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\right|}_{<1}dt + \int\limits_{N^c} \underbrace{\left|\frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{f(z_0)}\right|}_{=1}dt\right)\\
&< \frac{1}{2\pi}(\underbrace{\lambda(N)+\lambda(N^c)}_{=\lambda([0,2\pi])=2\pi})\\
&=1,
\end{align}
which of course is impossible. Note that $\lambda$ here just denotes the $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.